# html editor that give html code colouring inside php echo

Tags: php, html, ide

When we use `echo` in PHP, the code inside the quotes is HTML.

On some HTML editors that I use, they just highlight all of the HTML in one colour, so it makes it a little confusing.

Is there any IDE that gives colouring inside `echo`?

Comment: most editors do some kind of colour codeing

Comment: which operating system you are using in your machine ?

Answer (score 1):

The only real way you'd get confused echoing HTML is if there was a lot. You could always:

```
 echo {
 ?>
 HTML
 <?php
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the colouring for text inside " "? Try PHPStorm (http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/). They offer a 30 day free license to try out the product.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I actually started working on PHPStorm for the very same reason. I needed to work on an existing project where all the HTML was echo'ed in PHP.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not fully confident I understand what you want, but I believe you're asking if a code editor can also do HTML syntax-highlighting for HTML that exists inside PHP's `echo/print` statements. Normally not, because most editors see these as `strings`. However, you can embed PHP into HTML and that usually works a lot better:

```
<h1><?php print $someVar ?></h1>
```

If I misunderstood you, and you want syntax-highlighting for the web page...

There are plenty of javascript-based syntax-highlighters out there:

- [Rainbow](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDUQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fcraig.is%2Fmaking%2Frainbows&ei=uKhbUcjiEYicjALK3YDwDg&usg=AFQjCNFM5mj9Y65PNInr-lNDMr2D4GYDgA&sig2=JWj1OqCjOk2I36YULtJGWA&bvm=bv.44697112,d.cGE)
- [Prism](http://prismjs.com/)
- [Sunlight](http://sunlightjs.com/)

Comment: No.. for example _echo "<table><tr><td>bla bla bla</td></tr></table>";_ i want syntax-highlight for <table><tr><td>bla bla bla</td></tr></table>.

Comment: Why the down-vote? You're asking for syntax highlighting of HTML but in reality it's `string` when enclosed by quotes... most IDE editors do not highlight the code as HTML, they highlight it as a string. Some editors try - like the suggested PhpStorm (which I use). My solution is for you to embed PHP in the HTML markup instead of always `echo`ing a string ... that will work much better for free IDEs.

Comment: you're right. it's a `string`. i just wanted to find out, if there was an editor like i wanted.

Answer (score -1):

Try using Notepad++. It comes handy for many of the scripting languages. Here is the download link [Notepad++ download link](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/download/v6.3.2.html). Its free also. We use that for javascript editing. It works for php also

Comment: i have use Notepad++. but it's not like what i want